# Sed replace character after every number

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace a character after every integer number with sed.

Example:

`444 d`
should go:
`444,d`

EDIT: The answer of **stribizhev** helped me out to find a solution with sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

`sed -r 's/([0-9]+)./\1,/g'`

replaces an arbitary character after a number with a comma. The only problem is, that also a number at the end of the line creates an additional comma.

Comment: `sed -i 's/ /,/g' $strign`

Comment: Please show us your work so far.  What have you tried? Happy to help debug your code.

Comment: It's always trivial to match the text you want and MUCH harder to not match text you don't want so edit your question to provide sample input and expected output that includes the cases that you think will be hard to avoid false matches for (e.g. number-space-number, or newline-space-letter or...). As written all you need is `tr ' ' ','`. Also - what is a number to you? `1,000`? `3.14`? `5e7`? `-3`?

Comment: I was intended to search just integers. Sorry. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  can use capturing groups to do that:

```
sed 's/\(\d\+\)./\1,/g'
```

or (since with GNU sed you can avoid all the escaped parenthesis by using extended regular expressions)

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+)./\1,/g'
```

Here is a [demo showing what the regex does](https://regex101.com/r/vJ7hS1/1).

The `[0-9]+` pattern matches an integer number (without decimals) even Iinside longer strings, even within longer words.

Comment: Forgot to add: `.` matches any symbol but a newline. So, we will replace literally *any* character with anything you specify in the replacement part.

Comment: Should note that both of these solutions will work with GNU sed, but not other variants.  A solution that is portable is much more difficult. :-)

Comment: *Much* more difficult? `sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)./\1,/g'` should do it. I would prefer to use `[:digit:]` instead of `0-9` but I suspect that would limit portability.

Comment: Can you help explain how (\d+) captures multiple words ? Shouldn't it only capture one word ?

Comment: @user1074593: `\d+` matches 1 or more digits, it does not match "words". You said you needed to replace any character (that is matched with `.`) after a *number* (which is a sequence of digits). Please let me know if my logic does not meet your requirement.

Comment: @stribizhev a number isn't necessarily a sequence of digits. `3.14` is a number. We need the OP to edit his question to provide more comprehensive input/output and clarify his requirements.

Comment: Well, I surely know there are lots of *numbers*. The current question implies integer numbers. Let's wait for clarifications.

Comment: Thanks stribizhev. I found a solution, please see my edit. Do you have any idea why \d is not working with GNU sed 4.2.2?

Comment: If it does not work, it is not supported. There are varios vetsions of sed, all have their nuances. Perhaps, you could also try to use `[[:digit:]]+` or even `\digit+` with `-r` option to match an integer number. I updated my answer.